# UPSERT or INCREMENTAL update of table but with DELETE

Tags: postgresql, etl, upsert

I have a following problem.

We have two systems, an OLTP system and our Data Warehouse, both on PostgreSQL. I need to sync one table from OLTP system with DWH, so they're identical. I am using Foreign Data Wrapper for comunication between databases, so then sync could be straightforward and look like that:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE target_table;
INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

Unfortunately, the table is huge for the hardware we use (hundreds of millions of rows, and about 50GB of data), so this is massively time consuming.

I have then figured out a way to do it faster by doing incremental upsert, based on following approach.

1. Identify new rows in source table by taking rows with insert_time > SELECT max(insert_time) FROM target_table;
2. Identify rows, that need to be updated, by joining both tables on id and source_table.update_time > target_table.update_time.

That worked absolutely fine, however, a new problem arised - rows from source table can be removed, therefore I need to remove corresponding rows from target table. All approaches I tried are way to slow, like this one for example:

```
CREATE VIEW deleted_rows AS SELECT
target.row_id
FROM target
LEFT JOIN source USING(id)
WHERE source.id IS NULL;
```

Any idea how to solve this problem smartly and quickly? Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: How long do you need to sync data between OLAP and OLTP (hourly, daily, weekly) ?

Comment: @LuanHuynh everyday late night / early morning.

Comment: How many deleted rows per day on source ?  If not many, you can a table on source to stored `id` of deleted rows for each sync. Then, you can delete rows on target based on that table.

Comment: For my side, I don't need to delete the record on DWH, instead I created a column to keep track the status of record (1: open, 0: deleted).

Comment: @LuanHuynh, this is how it should be solved. The problem is that i am not responsible for the source data system, which is full of traps and other bad design issues.

Comment: To improve performance, please ask the person who can do it for you.

Comment: See if you can add an ON DELETE trigger on the source to log the deletions into a separate table.